# Xamarin.Forms: как из одного класса обращаться к элементам другого?

Tags: c#, wpf, классы, xaml, xamarin

Доброе время суток! Дано:

1. Есть ContentPage **Page1**, в ней через XAML вставляется ContentView **MyView** таким образом: `<local:MyView x:Name="MyView" />`;
2. В ContentView MyView есть некоторые элементы (Label, ListView и т.п.).

Вопрос: Как из **Page1** обращаться к элементам **MyView**? Ведь это 2 разных класса: Page1.xaml.cs, и MyView.xaml.cs

Comment: просто вопрос. а Вы умеете изменять свойства одного класса из другого? потому, что не могу понять проблему. либо у Вас что-то просто не работает(mvvm? inotifypropertychanged?), либо базовые принципы работы

Comment: @Dev по общим правилам ООП, да, конечно, но услышал мнение, что так нарушается принцип инкапсуляции. Я немного неверно сформулировал вопрос, имел в виду **как лучше** это сделать? Т.к. именно в WPF и MVVM я новичок.

Comment: что у вас там нарушается, без .. кода не разберешь. Если "лучше", то пишите  в MVVM и управляете свойствами одного объекта через публичные свойства другого. Тут вам надо читать примеры https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/ и сравнивать со своим кодом

Comment: @Dev, спасибо - разобрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Разобрался**.

1. В **MyView** сделал свойство **MyElement**, которое возвращает элемент (например, Listview);
2. В **Page1** обращаюсь к свойству из п.1 через указанное имя **x:Name**. Т.е. MyView.MyElement.